# Android Java : Save a file created by app to download folder

Tags: java, android, icalendar, outputstream, biweekly

i created a ical file with biweekly. I can write it to /Android/data/applicationfolder/files/Download with the following code:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Spiele.ics");

        if (file.exists ())
            file.delete ();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

            Biweekly.write(ical).go(outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But how do i save it to the standard download folder?
I tired some diffrent code with OutputStreamWriter but could not make it happen. Thanks.

Comment: In the same way. Only the path is different.

Comment: `I can write it to /Android/data/applicationfolder/files/Download`. That is not the full path. Have a look at file.getAbsolutePath() to know.

Comment: Yes, the path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/de.de.myapplication/files/Download/Spiele.ics
But how to change it?

Comment: Are you telling that you dont know the full path to the Download directory?

Comment: No i dont know how to set the path.

Comment: with 
```String setpath = "/sdcard/Download";``` 
and 
```File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(setpath), "Spiele.ics");``` 
It doesnt work.

Comment: This just adds the folders to the application folder

Comment: Yes. That you did wrong indeed.

Comment: Yeah i figured that Out... Maybe you could Help me!

Comment: So you did not try File file = new File("/sdcard/Download/Spiele.ics"); ? Or getExternalStorageDirectory() ?

Comment: Still dont work: with File file = new File("/sdcard/Download/Spiele.ics"); the i can not find the file in the file explorer.